# httpx.RemoteProtocolError: peer closed connection without sending complete message body

Tags: python, httpx

I am getting the above error despite setting the timeout to None for the httpx call. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```py
from httpx import stream

with stream("GET", url, params=url_parameters, headers=headers, timeout=None) as streamed_response:
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when using httpx via openapi-client autogenerated client

```
response = httpx.request(verify=client.verify_ssl,**kwargs,)
```

It turned out in *kwargs* parameter *headers* contained wrong authorization token.
So basically in my case that error meant "authorization error".
You might want to check if what you sending in your parameters is correct too.